# jquery+draggable / my input doesnt work after drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, drag

I need to change my input text after drop, but item is static

my code:

$(".item").draggable({

```
        revert: "invalid",
        snapTolerance: 20,
        snap:"#grid",
        containment:'#grid',

        start: function(){
            $("#grid").addClass("active");
            $(this).attr("id","big");   
            $(this).html("<input type='text' placeholder='Заголовок' class='head'>"); 

        },  

        stop: function(){
            $("#grid").removeClass("active");

        }       

 });
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle or show us some html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input based on the events like `start` `drag` `stop`

Here is a simple example which changes a input field value on different events and also the 
dragged element to a input text box

**code**

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
start: function() {
$("#t1").remove();
$(this).append("
<input type='text' placeholder='Заголовок' id='t1' class='head'>");
$("#t1").val("start");       
},
drag: function() {
$("#t1").val("Drag");
},
stop: function() {
$("#t1").val("Stop");
$(".head").val("Hello");
}
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YvJhE/47/)

Comment: need to add input field in mybox and change after draging

Comment: @user3036334 I have changed my answer , check the fiddle , may this is what you need